# Pointer in C gives all zero values

Tags: c, pointers

I made a number guessing game and want to print out all of the numbers that the user guessed while playing the game. However, when I run the program, it always prints out zero for all the values.

```
Your Tries: 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, %
```

It may be something wrong with the way I assigned the pointer value? Any help would be appreciated

```c
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int arr_size = 0;

int main()
{
    // Initialize random number with seed 2021.
    // Do not change this line, and do not call srand again.
    srand(2022);

    // the next line generate a random number between 1 to 100

    int n = (rand() % 100) + 1; 
    int *p = malloc(sizeof(int) * arr_size);
    
    while(1){
        
        int guess;
        scanf("%d", &guess);
        
        arr_size ++; 
        p = realloc(p, sizeof(int) * arr_size);
        p[arr_size-1] = guess;
        
        if(n > guess){
            printf("The Number is greater than %d\n", guess);
        }else if(n < guess){
            printf("The Number is less than %d\n", guess);
        }else{
            printf("You win. The Number is %d\n", guess);
            break;
        }
        
        
        
        if(guess == -1){
            printf("You input wrong number\nYou lose. The Number is %d", n);
            break;
        }
        
    }
    
    printf("Your Tries: ");
    for(int i = 0; i < arr_size; i ++){
        printf("%d, ", p[arr_size]);
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You malloc zero bytes... Change `int *p = malloc(sizeof(int) * arr_size);` into `int *p = NULL;`

Comment: When printing the array, you don't use the index 'i', you just index by arr_size.

Answer (score 1):

- `int *p = malloc(sizeof(int) * arr_size);`

  Allocating zero bytes isn't safe, the compiler can either return a null pointer or a pointer pointing at weird stuff, which may or may not be `realloc`atable(?). Replace this with `int *p = NULL;` to get deterministic, portable behavior instead.
- `p = realloc(p, sizeof(int) * arr_size);` There is no guarantee that `p` is pointing at the reallocated data after this. Correct use of realloc is:

  ```
  int* tmp = realloc(p, sizeof(int) * arr_size); 
  if(tmp == NULL) { /* handle errors */ }
  p = tmp;
  ```
- You never `free(p)`.
- There is no need to use dynamic allocation to begin with here, all you achieve with it is needless complexity, bloat and a much slower program. Just use `int p[100];` and watch all your problems go away, while at the same time massively improving execution speed.
- `printf("%d, ", p[arr_size]);` is nonsense and out of bounds, use `p[i]`.

Comment: Allocating 0 is not _not safe_.  True it may return 0 or some pointer, but that is not the problem here as OP's code handles either well (aside from the `realloc()` snafu).  True that `int *p = NULL;` is a better choice.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Reallocing a pointer returned by `malloc(0)` doesn't seem defined by the standard at all. You'd have to read that behavior "between the lines". Maybe this makes for a separate "language lawyer" question.

Comment: My read with "If the size of the space requested is zero, the behavior is implementation-defined: either a null pointer is returned to indicate an error, or the behavior is as if the size were some nonzero value, except that the returned pointer shall not be used to access an object." and "if ptr does not match a pointer earlier returned by a memory management function" imply it is OK.  Yes, may make for a good question.  IMO, C17 did not clear up `*alloc(0)` and just muddied the waters.  I avoid `*alloc(0)` in all cases now.